# Looping Through an Array of Objects and Accessing Each Property

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops

I've looked at other posts for ideas and solutions and they've provided help, but for my particular problem, I still can't get mine to work. I have two objects that I push into an array. Under the [FIRST TRY], I am able to loop through and have the correct values displayed in alert boxes, however, I cannot access each property of my object. In my SECOND TRY, I try and use jquery to access them, but in my alert boxes, the variables are displayed as 'Undefined'. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

file.js

```
var x_array=[]

var objC = {
firstname: "Jane",
lastname: "Doe",
email: "jdoe@email.com"
};

var objD = {
firstname: "Jordan",
lastname: "Michael",
email: "jmichael@email.com"
};
x_array.push(objC);
x_array.push(objD);

// FIRST TRY
for (var i = 0; i < x_array.length; i++) {
   var object = x_array[i];
for (var property in object) {
    alert("Name: "+ i + ':' + property + '=' + object[property]);
    }
}
    alert("Begin Trying it another way"); // SECOND TRY 

$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(MyArray))).each(function() {  
var HisName = this.name;
var HisAge = this.age;
alert("The persons name is "+HisName+' and their age is ' +HisAge);
});
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/6hpwn9cq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It loops through all the objects in the array and loop through all its key value pair.

```
var x_array=[]

var objC = {
firstname: "Jane",
lastname: "Doe",
email: "jdoe@email.com"
};

var objD = {
firstname: "Jordan",
lastname: "Michael",
email: "jmichael@email.com"
};
x_array.push(objC);
x_array.push(objD);

// FIRST TRY
for (var i = 0; i < x_array.length; i++) {
   var objStr = " "
   Object.keys(x_array[i]).forEach(function(key) {
       if(key !="email"){
          objStr += key + ":" + x_array[i][key] + " ";
       }
   });
   alert(objStr);
}
```

Comment: This works well. But if I wanted to display just the first name and the last name and leave out the email, is this possible? Could I identy each of the key value pairs somehow>?

Comment: This works too I believe. I'm just trying to tweak it for formatting and append it to a section. THanks for your help though. From this I should be able to make any other changes I might need in the future. Thanks